# File exists @ dir_s_mkdir when I'm not calling mk_dir

Tags: ruby, fileutils

I'm trying to write a simple file transfer script:

```
def copy_vscode_files(in_or_out)
  vsc_path = Paths.base_path[@year] + Paths.vscode_path
  Paths.vscode_files.each do |file|
    path = vsc_path + "/#{file}"
    case in_or_out
      when "in" then    FileUtils.cp_r(path, transfer_path)
      when "out" then   FileUtils.cp_r(transfer_path, path)
    end
  end
end
```

Copying in works fine but when I try to copy out I get

```
Errno::EEXIST: File exists @ dir_s_mkdir - /Users/TuzsNewMacBook/Library/Application Support/Code/User/keybindings.json
```

which is confusing me because I'm never calling `mkdir` in this method or in any of the methods it calls.

It's also confusing because while yes, the file it mentions does indeed exist, "copying in" also involves overwriting an existing file.

Comment: `cp_r` is a recursive copy, including any and all subdirectories, so it definitely *will* need to call `mkdir` at some point if there exists any subdirectory. Note that e.g. macOS will actually create tons of hidden subdirectories.

Comment: But isn't it encountering this error on the first file, which is simply a file and not a directory?

Comment: Presumably `transfer_path` is a method. What does it return? If it returns a directory that might be the problem, as `in` would work but `out` would raise an exception. As to why you are getting the particular error message, search for "eexists" [here](https://blog.honeybadger.io/understanding-rubys-strange-errno-exceptions/).

Comment: Yeah it wound up being dumb: as you may notice in the code `path` got a filename appended to it, whereas `transfer_path` is a path to a folder. So, moving a file to a folder works. But moving a folder to a file... obviously not. Gods of SO, what should I do with this post? Delete it?

Comment: I think the question has value, but for it to make sense you need to edit it to show the value of `transfer_path`. That might be done most easily by making `transfer_path` an argument (rather than a method) and then invoke the method with example values of the two arguments. As far as answering the question, I suggest you provide an answer yourself (not in the question, but as an answer.) I say the question has merit because anyone could encounter the problem.

Comment: I just happened to see your comment. You need to remember to add @<username> to your comments so the persons to which they are directed will be notified by SO.